# How to set up Enide Studio in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

after i install the Enide Studio from [link](http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/) and extract the zip file to my desktop i can't start the program and i can't find any documentation on there site to know how to do this on linux all the example on windows so please help.

Comment: Could you post any error messages you may get when starting it? Otherwise, could you try to start it from the command line and post the output?